# How does Numpy infers dtype for array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, int

Can anyone please help me to understand that from where does Numpy's array function infers data type.

I understand it basically infers from the kind of value that has been assigned to the array.

For Example:

```
> data = [1,2,3,4]
> arr = np.array(data)
```

So in the above lines the "arr" will have the `dtype('int64')` or `dtype('int32')`.

What I am trying to understand is how does it decides whether to give it a `int64` or a `int32`?

I understand that it might be a trivial question but I am just trying to understand that how does it work as I was recently asked this in an interview.

Comment: maybe [this link](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html) might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html),

> Some types, such as int and intp, have differing bitsizes, dependent on the platforms (e.g. 32-bit vs. 64-bit machines).

So, on 32-bit machines, `np.array([1,2,3,4])` returns an array of dtype `int32`, but on 64-bit machines it returns an array of dtype `int64`.

Answer (score 3):

Numeric data types include integers and floats.

If we have an array that contains both `integers` and `floating point numbers`, `numpy` will assign the entire array to the `float` data type so the decimal points are not lost.

An integer will never have a decimal point. So for example, 2.55 would be stored as 2

As mentioned by @unutbu `int32` and `int64` depends on the type of bit-machines you have, whether it is a 32 bit-machine or a 64 bit-machine

`Strings`, are values that contain `numbers` and/or `characters`. For example, a string might be a word, a sentence, or several sentences. The most general `dtype=string` will be assigned to your array if your array has mixed types (numbers and strings).

To have a complete detailed look, you can have a look at [this website of scipy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Answer (score 2):

In Python3 (and a basic 32 bit machine), int32 v int64 depends on the size of the input

```
In [447]: np.array(123456789)
Out[447]: array(123456789)

In [448]: _.dtype
Out[448]: dtype('int32')

In [449]: np.array(12345678901234)
Out[449]: array(12345678901234, dtype=int64)
```

From the `np.array` docs:

> dtype: The desired data-type for the array.  If not given, then
>       the type will be determined as the minimum type required
>       to hold the objects in the sequence.  This argument can only
>       be used to 'upcast' the array.

Looks like `int32` is the smallest default int size (at least with my configuration).  The is also the value of `np.int_`.

As an example of the disallowed downcast:

```
In [456]: np.array(12345678901234, dtype=np.int32)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-456-da7c96e4b0b3> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array(12345678901234, dtype=np.int32)

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some kind of a hierarchical treatment, where it uses the most conservative yet also all-encompassing type that can "legally" represent the input. If you just have integers, you will preserve all of the elements using int32/64. As soon as you introduce a float, you need to use float32/64 to preserve all of the elements of the array, and you can always back-convert a `float` to an `int`. As soon as you introduce a string, you need to use strings to legally represent everything in the array, and again, you can always back-convert to `float` or `int` if you need to

Ex:

```
>>> array([1]).dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> array([1, 2.0]).dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> array([1, 2.0, 'a']).dtype
dtype('S3')
```

In short, it is pretty smart about it ;)